# How to convert my simple table to the Datatables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

mytable.php

```
<table id="tableid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">A</th>
            <th scope="col">B</th>  
            <th scope="col">C</th> 
            <th scope="col">D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hello Guys, Can anyone help me how to convert my code to the Datatables? Sorry Guys for this question I try to convert but it didn't work. I'm a beginner and still learning how to use tables

Comment: Do you mean the jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)?

Comment: yes sir........

Comment: `$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tableid').DataTable();
} );` didn't work? What have you done so far?

Comment: yes, sir, I try this in my code but it didn't work

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

Comment: then this is the link i used

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you checked the dev–console for error–msgs? Might be worth posting a fiddle...

Answer (score 1):

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">

 <tr>
......
</tr>
</table>
```

In addition to the above code, the following Javascript library files are loaded for use in this example:

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js